# MIPS assembly questions

Tags: mips

I am working on my assignment and I have a few questions.

1. Do I have to always push arguments/return value registers to the stack? If the answer is yes where do I do it? in caller or callee procedure?
2. I am trying to optimize my instruction. I wonder if I can change from

   ```
   slt $t0, $a0, a1    #check if a<b
   beq $t0,$zero, ELSE     #if $a>b, $t0 = 0, go to else
   addi $v0, $zero,1       #a<b, return 1
   j    exit               #end if, jump to exit
   ELSE: addi $v1, $zero, 0 #a>b, return 0
   exit: jr  $ra           #return to address
   ```

   to

   ```
   slt  $v0, $a0, a1    #if a<b, $v0 =1 and if a>b, $v0 = 0
   jr   $ra             #return to address
   ```

Comment: 1) Depends on the calling convention. 2) What happened to `$v1` in your optimization?

Comment: I didn't use $v1

Answer (score 1):

MIPS divides registers into preserved and nonpreserved categories. The preserved registers include `$s0 – $s7` (hence their name, saved). The nonpreserved registers include `$t0 – $t9` (hence their name, temporary). A function must save and restore any of the preserved registers that it wishes to use, but it can change the nonpreserved registers freely.

The callee must save and restore any preserved
registers that it wishes to use. The callee may change any of the nonpreserved
registers. Hence, if the caller is holding active data in a nonpreserved register,
the caller needs to save that nonpreserved register before making the function call and then needs to restore it afterward.

For these reasons, preserved
registers are also called *callee-save*, and nonpreserved registers are called
*caller-save*.